# How to add item to string array in activity 'a' by click on the button in activity 'b'?

Tags: android, sqlite, search

I have a problem. I want to add some items to my list view which is in activity 'b'  by click on the button or other view in activity 'a'. For example:

My Activity 'a' :

```
b.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener()
{
@Override
  public void onClick(view v)
{
// add item to myarray which there in activity 'b'
    myArray.add("");
}});


}
```

My Activity 'b' :

```
ArrayList<String> myArray;
```

Hope to get my purpose. Thank-you.

Comment: use interface callback or event bus

Answer (score 0):

You can create a third object ( A public class where you put the ArrayList ) and access it every time you need its values : Update it from first activity and get values from second activity.

Activity 1:

```
b.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener()
{
@Override
  public void onClick(view v)
{
    Utilities.addValue("String");
}});
}
```

Activity 2:

```
ArrayList<String> myArray = Utilities.getArrayList();
```

Utility Class:

```
public static class Utilities {
    static ArrayList<String> mArrayList;

    public static void addValue(String a){
        if (null == mArrayList) {
            mArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        mArrayList.add(a);
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getArrayList(){
        return mArrayList;
    }
}
```